# Using get_user_info(user_id) Discord Python

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I've made a command for find a user's information by their ID.
I did the following code:

```
userId = UserToFind[0]
hi = self.get_user_info(userId)
await self.safe_send_message(channel,"It's" + hi)
```

While doing so, it says that couldn't convert `generator` to a simple `str`.

I also tried doing   `await self.safe_send_message(channel,"It's" + hi.name)`, but it gives me another error: `generator object has no atribute name`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[Client.get_user_info](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info) is a coroutine, meaning you must await that too

```
hi = await self.get_user_info(userId)
```

Calling the method without awaiting it will return a generator, specifically a coroutine object.

Comment: Indeed that works. 
I just don't get something.
I've made the command, and everytime I do a ID, it says  `user not found`. I tried making it by default find myself, for check if was a issue finding the ID by the command itself,  and still saying the same thing.

Comment: You are using IDs (17/18 chars) and not discriminators (#0000) right? Head to your appearence settings and turn on developer mode, then you can copy ID from the right click menu. Remember to click a name instead of an ID or you'll get the message ID instead of the member ID

Comment: I know. But it keeps saying that isn't found.
I went on my server, clicked over me, and "copy ID", and still.

Comment: Which version of discord.py are you on? 0.16.X or 1.0? If you are on the latter, you need to ensure `userId` is an int... Other than that, I really cannot think of any other issues :/